# for loop to create line plots for individual columns in r

Tags: r, csv, pdf, plot, export

I'm brand new to [r](/questions/tagged/r) and can't seem to figure this out. I have a [csv](/questions/tagged/csv) and need to [plot](/questions/tagged/plot) each column as a its own unique line plot, and then output those plots to a csv. Here's what I have for the plotting, however when I simply run the code to create the plots nothing is outputted in [r-studio](/questions/tagged/r-studio).

```
for(i in 3:50){
  x <- data[,i]
  y <- data[,2]
  plot(x,type="l", main=names(data[i]), ylab="cases", xlab="month")
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to make this work? I just need to create individual plots for each column (each column corresponds to an individual country), and then output all of those plots onto one single [pdf](/questions/tagged/pdf).

Comment: You can output it to a `pdf` or a .jpeg

Comment: As a start, you define `y` but never use it. Try changing `plot(x, type = "l", ...)` to `plot(x, y, type = "l", ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work (but you did not provide a sample of the data to test it):

```
pdf("myplots.pdf")
for(i in 3:50){
  x <- data[,i]
  y <- data[,2]
  plot(x, y, type="l", main=names(data)[i], ylab="cases", xlab="month")
}
dev.off()
```

The file will be in your current working directory (`getwd()`). Each page will be a separate plot.